# How to change the primary language for google services?

Tags: google-account, google-chrome, localization

Even though I set the primary language to Polish and the second language to English, Google services are displayed in Turkish.

I would like the menu on Google websites to be in Polish. I don't know how to configure it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.